# jdk11 scala 2.12.8 compatibility

Tags: java, scala, playframework, guice, java-11

My scala 2.12.8 project was working fine with jdk8, after solving a few compiling issues I managed to build the scala 2.12.8 project with jdk11. However I got an run time class loading exception as following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/http/JavaHttpFiltersDelegate$AjcClosure1
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingProcessor$1.visit(UntargettedBindingProcessor.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingProcessor$1.visit(UntargettedBindingProcessor.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingImpl.acceptTargetVisitor(UntargettedBindingImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingProcessor.visit(UntargettedBindingProcessor.java:35)
    at com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingProcessor.visit(UntargettedBindingProcessor.java:27)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingImpl.acceptVisitor(BindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:186)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:185)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:51)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:25)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.http.JavaHttpFiltersDelegate$AjcClosure1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
```

According to scala website https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

> As of Scala 2.13.0, 2.12.8 and 2.11.12, JDK 11 support is incomplete. Notably, scalac will not enforce the restrictions of the Java Platform Module System, which means that code that typechecks may incur linkage errors at runtime.

I'm not sure if the error I got is related to the the issue mentioned by the scala website. If not any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: This issue does not seems to be the error mentioned in the documentation as Play supports JDK, it might be a library compatibility issue, make sure you have the right play version you can check their CI https://travis-ci.com/playframework/playframework

Comment: The `AjcClosure` class probably means that you're using AspectJ. If so, that seems to be a problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with options shown on the image.

[image: Link]

1. Go to "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Scala Compiler | Scala Compile Server"
2. Check "Use compiler server"
3. Select JDK installed from the drop-menu field.